# How do I tweak CSS on the Django 1.2.3 admin media?

Tags: django, django-admin, customization, redhat

I would like to make CSS-only adjustments to the admin interface (on an RHEL box I don't have sysadmin privileges to). To that end, I would like a local version of /media/ to tweak.

http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/static-files/ (but not http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/howto/static-files/) suggests running a manage.py collectstatic or manage.py findstatic, and my Django 1.2.3 manage.py does not recognize those commands. Adding 'django.contrib.staticfiles' to my INSTALLED_APPS also broke things (not found).

I would like to customize the CSS, and the way I envision doing that is by getting a private copy of the media for Django's admin and changing from there. What are my best options for a Django 1.2.3 installation?

Comment: why 'django.contrib.staticfiles' !!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just go to your django installation directory, browser to django->contrib-> admin-> directory and copy paste the media folder to your django projects media directory.

Let us say you have your media in `project/media` which is statically rendered to web as /media/. If you copy your admin media in `project/media` your admin media web url would be `/media/admin/` hence in your settings.py file: `ADMIN_MEDIA_PREFIX = '/media/admin/'`

You may then modify your css in media directory as you wish to change the look of admin site.

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to do it:

1: Download a fresh copy of Django and unpack it. Under the Django-x.x.x directory was a media directory.

2: Tar/transfer/untar the media directory on my target machine.

3: Change the CSS as needed.

4: When calling python manage.py runserver, add a flag of --adminmedia=./media .